# How to read tag name using workflow_run

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-delivery

I'm using Github actions with two workflows: CI and CD. The CI workflow is triggered for new tags like `v1.1.1` and pull requests to develop and hotfix branches.

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    tags: v[1-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+
    
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop, hotfix*]
```

The CD workflow is triggered when the previous workflow (CI) is completed.

```
name: CD

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['CI']
    push:
      tags: v[1-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+
    types:
      - completed
```

Currently, my goal is to generate packages (Docker images) based on the name of the new tag. I'm trying to read the new tag name in the CD workflow using the action [dawidd6/action-get-tag@v1](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-get-tag):

```
- name: Get tag
  id: tag
  uses: dawidd6/action-get-tag@v1
- name: Use tag
  run: echo ${{steps.tag.outputs.tag}}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Run dawidd6/action-get-tag@v1
env:
  IMAGE_NAME: open-tuna-api
Error: Not a tag ref (refs/heads/master)
```

My question is: how to read the tag name in my CD workflow that is triggering after the CI workflow?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can get the tag without using an action, with `${GITHUB_REF##*/}`.

Sample test workflow:

```
name: Experiment

on:
  push:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Debug
      run: echo "Works. Tag is ${GITHUB_REF##*/}"
```

As for the chained workflows you mention - I am not sure it is possible to get the tag of the ancestor workflow, since [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) mentions it is triggered on the default branch, and the last commit on that branch.

Comment: Hi @DannyB! Seems that you are right. It is not possible to get the tag name using `workflow_run`. You know any other way to achieve this goal (use the tag name in a workflow triggered by `workflow_run`). Maybe a way to set the tag name as an output of the first workflow... Thanks!

Comment: Can't think of a way to do it, although I totally understand the need. Perhaps open a discussion on GitHub forums.

Comment: [Done!](https://github.community/t/passing-data-between-workflows-when-using-workflow-run/153955)

Answer (score 0):

As described in the github discussion: [Workflow_run doen't preserve github.ref? #27124](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27124)

To access the tag name, that is the initial ref that triggered the `workflow_run`, you need to use:

```
${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
```